# Which os is better for development : Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, debian, operating-system

Are there any real differences between them?

I want to program in java and python. And of corse be a normal user: internet, etc

Which one will give me less headaches/more satisfaction ?

And which is better for a server machine ?

Thank you

Comment: I disagree with closing this as subjective and argumentative.  There are some real, objective (if subtle) differences between the two distributions, and none of the answers I've read so far are argumentative.

Comment: @Forest: no, every *nix distribution is almost exactly the same.

Comment: @Longpoke: I've used Slackware in the mid-90s, then Debian, Corel Linux, Red Hat, Fedora, Ubuntu and now back to Debian.  There's **NO WAY** all Linux distribution are almost exactly the same.  Let alone every *nix distribution.  (OS X is fully POSIX compliant Un*x and you're smoking heavy stuff if you think OS X, Open Solaris, and all the Linux distros are *almost exactly the same*)

Comment: @Longpoke: Read Forest's answer (+1 to Forest btw)

Comment: nah, see Bryan Oakley's answer.

Comment: Debian is more stable... ubuntu not that much... if you are somebody who likes stability... then choose debian

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, development is almost exactly the same for both.  They're both quite suitable for server machines.  The fundamental difference is that Debian follows a Free software ideology, while Ubuntu sacrifices that purity for practicality when no Free equivalent exists for important proprietary software.

If you choose Debian, you will have a choice of distribution series ("unstable" / "testing") that may get you newer releases of pre-packaged software a few months sooner than Ubuntu.  Unless your development projects require bleeding-edge kernel or support libraries, this probably won't matter to you at all.

If you choose Ubuntu, certain proprietary software might be easier to install because it will be available through package repositories.  For example, nVidia's proprietary video driver.  That's not to say you can't make such things work on Debian; they will simply be easier on Ubuntu.

I used Ubuntu for years, for these reasons:

- Ubuntu has a free multi-platform build farm and software hosting system called [Personal Package Archives](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).  (Only to be used for freely redistributable software, of course.)
- The Ubuntu bug reporting/tracking system is far more user friendly than Debian's.
- Software packages I develop are guaranteed to work (with no extra dependency testing) for Ubuntu users, of which there are many.

After replacing my Nvidia GPU with an AMD (for better drivers) and finding package repository tools that fit my workflow, I eventually switched to Debian.

Answer (score 4):

Both use Debian packages and Ubuntu is based on Debian but is more user friendly. Everything yo can do on one you can do on the other. I'd recommend Ubuntu if your new to linux on a Desktop. Though when it comes to servers I'd recommend Debian as it has less stuff "taken out" basically.

Answer (score 2):

java and python would most likely run the same on both.

With Ubuntu you get additional space of support and active community, and perhaps larger user base.

So if and when you face a particular problem, chances are with Ubuntu, the solution will appear faster.

(although, whatever works on this should work on the other as well in theory)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is the more user-friendly of the two (I think Ubuntu is actually one of **the** most newbie-friendly Linux distros), so if you are new to Linux, Ubuntu is the way to go.  Otherwise, the packages are mostly the same except for branding, so it's pretty much your choice.

Comment: Eleven years later, I would like to introduce Mint (Ubuntu-based), Solus (independent), and arguably Manjaro (Arch-based) into the list of *the* most user-friendly systems.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu it is a bit easier to install packages for Java development, but it doesn't really matter that much. Remember that Ubuntu is based on Debian, so it works the same. Ubuntu just adds more user-friendly GUI's.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is better. They both support the same tools and libraries. They are both linux. Anything and everything you can do on one you can do on the other.